# Transferring data from child frame to parent frame in java

Tags: java

I am new in Java, My question is that, I have made a main frame in java containing buttons. When buttons are pressed new frames are called i.e. by calling their constrctors(new childFrame();) etc. 
These child frames contains forms for entering and editing data. I want that data to transfer from child frame to main frame.
 How this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

As every frame is an object and every object can access methods and variables of the objects/classes containing them, I would suggest you to create the child frames inside the parent frame's class and store them as a local field. This way you should be able to access data in both directions. The variables of the child frame you want to exchange have to be public to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if there are so many classes and child frames so it is difficult to put all the classes in one frame. Is there is another way to do this?

Comment: Please post how the objects that have to communicate are stored. A piece of code tells more than 1000 words... You may/should shorten it, of course.